# Why does traceroute to my home router go outside of my local network?

Tags: linux, man-in-the-middle, router, traceroute

Earlier today, I wanted to access the admin web server of my router.
But for some reason, I was not able to access it, the web browser telling me there was no server on that address.

I had internet connection, so I was a bit surprised.
I first pinged my router, which worked fine.
Then, after checking my route, which seemed correct, I decided to make a `traceroute`.
And I got that :

```
$ traceroute to 198.168.8.1 (198.168.8.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.8.1  1.184 ms  2.162 ms  2.660 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.4.2.17  44.729 ms 10.4.0.17  64.094 ms 10.4.1.17  64.258 ms
 4  10.187.154.251  64.533 ms  64.487 ms  64.441 ms
 5  77.136.134.1  64.304 ms  64.250 ms  64.198 ms
 6  77.136.10.34  64.043 ms  63.869 ms  62.807 ms
 7  77.136.10.245  68.157 ms  41.670 ms  41.429 ms
 8  77.136.10.245  40.912 ms  45.589 ms  48.417 ms
 9  198.32.118.240  168.585 ms  168.633 ms  169.538 ms
10  68.67.63.81  175.225 ms  169.396 ms 192.252.143.186  169.601 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * 198.168.8.1  152.839 ms *
```

This seems weird to me and extremely suspicious.

So I tried on another computer and the `traceroute` seems normal, one hop and that's it, but the web server was not accessible either.
That same computer restarted on Windows and tried to access the router's web server, and at that point it worked.
It also worked again on my first computer, and the `traceroute` was once again normal (one hop).

After some time, it is now again showing me a `traceroute` going out of my home LAN before going back. But now, the router's web server works.

So now, I'm lost...

Is there any legit possible explanation why it is going outside my LAN when I do a traceroute ?

I don't have any VPN on at the moment and here are my routes :

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

I'm on Linux, and my router is a 4G router Huawei B525s-23a

Comment: The real IP address of the admin interface of your router is __192__.168.8.1 not __198__.168.8.1, i.e. **you have a typo**. The first IP address is a non-routeable local IP address which is used for internal networks, the second IP address is an external one which belongs to a netblock of softimage.

Comment: ahah, yes indeed. Ah, the little things... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steffen Ullrich mentions in his comment, the problem was a simple typo in your `traceroute` script.

You wrote

```
traceroute 198.168.8.1
```

but it should be

```
traceroute 192.168.8.1
```